# if not exists begin update insert error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I look at the code and checking again and again, really don't know what happen to my code and getting error below -

```
strSql=     "BEGIN if (not EXISTS (select empno tablenameA where empno = @empno)) " & _
            " begin " & _
            " Update tablenameA set ota_verifier = @ota_verifier, ota_approval = @ota_approval, ota_payroll = @ota_payroll, ota_hr = @ota_hr, " & _
            " ota_viewall = @ota_viewall, ota_HRMng = @ota_HRMng, ota_MD = @ota_MD, ota_SP=@ota_SP " & _
            " WHERE empno =  @empno " & _
            " end    " & _
            " else   " & _
            " begin  " & _
            " Insert INTO tablenameA (empno, ota_empname, ota_deptcode, ota_verifier, ota_approval,  ota_payroll, ota_hr, ota_viewall, ota_AD, ota_HRMng, ota_MD, ota_SP) " & _
            " VALUES (@empno, @ota_empname, @ota_deptcode, @ota_verifier, @ota_approval, @ota_payroll, @ota_hr, @ota_viewall, @ota_AD, @ota_HRMng, @ota_MD, @ota_SP) " & _
            "   end  " & _
            "   END "
```

> Incorrect syntax near '.'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need add FROM **

```
strSql=     "BEGIN if (not EXISTS (select ota_empno FROM [GOGREEN].[dbo].[tbOvertimeAccess] where ota_empno = @ota_empno)) " & _
            " begin " & _
            " Update tbOvertimeAccess set ota_verifier = @ota_verifier, ota_approval = @ota_approval, ota_payroll = @ota_payroll, ota_hr = @ota_hr, " & _
            " ota_viewall = @ota_viewall, ota_HRMng = @ota_HRMng, ota_MD = @ota_MD, ota_SP=@ota_SP " & _
            " WHERE ota_empno =  @ota_empno " & _
            " end    " & _
            " else   " & _
            " begin  " & _
            " Insert INTO tbOvertimeAccess (ota_empno, ota_empname, ota_deptcode, ota_verifier, ota_approval,  ota_payroll, ota_hr, ota_viewall, ota_AD, ota_HRMng, ota_MD, ota_SP) " & _
            " VALUES (@ota_empno, @ota_empname, @ota_deptcode, @ota_verifier, @ota_approval, @ota_payroll, @ota_hr, @ota_viewall, @ota_AD, @ota_HRMng, @ota_MD, @ota_SP) " & _
            "   end  " & _
            "   END "
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a `FROM` keyword between `empno` and `tablenameA`

```
strSql=     "BEGIN if (not EXISTS (select empno tablenameA where empno = @empno)) "
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
strSql=     "BEGIN if (not EXISTS (select empno FROM tablenameA where empno = @empno)) " & _
            " begin " & _
            " Update tablenameA set ota_verifier = @ota_verifier, ota_approval = @ota_approval, ota_payroll = @ota_payroll, ota_hr = @ota_hr, " & _
            " ota_viewall = @ota_viewall, ota_HRMng = @ota_HRMng, ota_MD = @ota_MD, ota_SP=@ota_SP " & _
            " WHERE empno =  @empno " & _
            " end    " & _
            " else   " & _
            " begin  " & _
            " Insert INTO tablenameA (empno, ota_empname, ota_deptcode, ota_verifier, ota_approval,  ota_payroll, ota_hr, ota_viewall, ota_AD, ota_HRMng, ota_MD, ota_SP) " & _
            " VALUES (@empno, @ota_empname, @ota_deptcode, @ota_verifier, @ota_approval, @ota_payroll, @ota_hr, @ota_viewall, @ota_AD, @ota_HRMng, @ota_MD, @ota_SP) " & _
            "   end  " & _
            "   END "
```